# C# EPPlus How to hide range of columns

Tags: c#, epplus

I am working with EPPlus which generate excel file. now i have to hide range of columns. this code i used to hide range of columns in one go.

```
var rangecol = ws.Cells["M1:P1"];
var hiddenColumns = rangecol
.Select(cell => cell.Start.Column)
.Distinct()
.Select(rangecol.Worksheet.Column)
.ToList();

foreach (var column in hiddenColumns)
{
    column.Hidden = true;
}
```

the above code is working and hiding columns but if there are 4 columns in range then it is hiding 4 columns individually not hide in one block. i want 4 columns should be hide in one block instead of 4 blocks.

please tell me what mistake is there in my code for which groups of columns are not getting hidden in one block. Thanks

Comment: I just hid a number of columns in an empty excel sheet and found no way to unhide them as a block, i.e. they were hidden individually. Are you certain block hiding is a feature in excel?

Comment: in excel you can select multiple columns and hide from context menu. then you will see those columns hide in a block but EPPlus hide each columns that is my issue. so i am curious to know can i do the same kind of hide from EPPlus?

Comment: Yes, I understood the question. But my experience is that it hides each column, not the block.

Comment: yes that is the problem that it is hiding each column but not hiding columns in block which excel does when we select multiple columns and hide from excel. please tell me how to hide columns in block from EPPlus instead of each column hiding. thanks